# Most efficient way to send image to frontend

Tags: file-upload, frontend, google-cloud-storage, backend, multipartform-data

I have images stored in Google Cloud Storage. Whenever my frontend (Swift) requests a certain image I would like to send the image as quickly and efficiently as possible from my backend.

Conveniently, Google Cloud Storage has direct image links for every image.

**Is it most efficient to send a multipart/form-data the same way I send an image captured by a user in the front end to the backend? Or is it more efficient to send the URL of the image stored in the cloud where the frontend can proceed to download the image from that URL?**

Answer (score 1):

This can indeed be done through a [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) which provides limited permission and time to make a request. With signed URLs authentication information is contained in their query string, allowing users without credentials to perform specific actions on a resource.

I would like to point out however that Signed URLs can only be used to access resources in Cloud Storage through [XML API endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpointshttps://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints).

Since you are using Swift for your frontend I would also like to direct you to explore [Google APIs for iOS](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#build-apis-for-ios), such as [CocoaPods](https://developers.google.com/ios/guides/cocoapods?_ga=2.31757438.119806445.1592950098-640404904.1584421134).